# How did Omni-Man keep his secret identity hidden?

Tags: invincible

Omni-Man is a Viltrumite living on Earth. He is also known by his regular name: Nolan Grayson. As a way to make money, and to preserve his identity as Omni-Man, Nolan takes a job as an author for travel books.

> When Nolan disappears from Earth after fighting Mark,

Cecil mentions that

> "all his travel books always sold well, but sales will see a significant spike after his death."

This indicates that Nolan's death would drive up sales of his books even more, so he must be well known and pretty popular.

How is it that no one would recognise Nolan Grayson as the revered Omni-Man? Omni-Man didn't wear a mask, so it's incredibly easy to see his face. Was *Nolan Grayson - The Author* somehow different in appearance from *Nolan Grayson - Omni-Man*? Did no one ever make the connection?

Comment: Have you heard of... Superman?

Comment: I'd imagine it's a case of *"Hey, you look just like Omni-Man*", *"Yeah, a lot of people say that. I don't see it myself".*

Comment: Lots of authors don't have a jacket photo. For example, feel free to tell me whether Greg Egan looks like Omni-Man

Comment: @Valorum - r.e. your last comment, if someone can prove that then it would be a solid answer

Comment: I have a better example: I can guarantee that no one can describe what Jack Mckinney, the author of a *Robotech* novels looks like. People might assume that travel witer "Nolan Grayson" is simply a house pseudonym; after all, how could a single person  possibly travel *that* much?

Comment: Cecil saying "all his travel books always sold well, but sales will see a significant spike after his death." is Cecil saying that his agency will pay the Graysons survivor's benefits by surreptitiously buying copies of Nolan's books in large quantities.

Comment: @notovny There's a known and [studied](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016726812300118X) real world phenomenon in which the death of an author, especially if that author was famous and died early, will usually be followed by a massive increase in sales of that author's books. Why do you think Cecil is promising surreptitious purchases when the general public will do exactly what he says will happen without him needing to interfere beyond announcing Nolan's death?

Comment: @8bittree Because in the scene in question, (S1E8, about 26 minutes in) Cecil explains it as one of the things he is doing to ease the Grayson's' burden in a post-Omni-man world.. Cecil isn't saying things he thinks will happen in that conversation, he's talking about things he's already done, will do, or will make happen, if Debbie's fine with it, and he's giving her the public cover stories.

Comment: @notovny After reviewing the scene, I can see where you're coming from. I'm not yet convinced it's the intended interpretation, but it is a very plausible one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the TV show it's simply [*hand-waved*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HandWave). Norms (and in this case, other supers) don't recognise supers in their day clothes, even when they've seen them in real life.

> **Mark:** I never recognized you before.
>
> **Eve:** No one does. It's a psychology thing. If you don't expect to see a superhero in your school, you don't see a superhero in your school.

In the comics, Atom Eve is extremely surprised that she's recognised, even by someone who knows her personally. Again, zero explanation is offered.

[image]
<sub><sup>[**Invincible #004**](https://imagecomics.fandom.com/wiki/Invincible_Vol_1_4)</sup></sub>

Comment: And the best part is...this really works. There's tons of stories about celebrities who don't wear anything in the way of a disguise except for different clothes, changing their hair or yes, wearing glasses, who can be completely unrecognized. Shakira is a good example: she attended a semester at UCLA using her real name and flew completely under the radar because no one ever thought of internationally known singer Shakira attending classes.

Comment: Also pretty much the reason no one spots Mark and Eve flying away from school - "no one looks up"